# Is it possible to find the list of attributes which would yield to the greatest sum without brute forcing?

Tags: algorithm

I have about 2M records stored in a table.
Each record has a number and about 5K boolean attributes.

So the table looks something like this.

```
3, T, F, T, F, T, T, ...
29, F, F, T, F, T, T, ...
...
-87, T, F, T, F, T, T, ...
98, F, F, T, F, F, T, ...
```

And I defined `SUM(A, B)` as the sum of the numbers where Ath and Bth attributes are true.
For example, from the sample data above: `SUM(1, 3) = 3 + ... + (-87)` because the 1st and the 3rd attributes are T for 3 and -87

```
3, (T), F, (T), F, T, T, ...
29, (F), F, (T), F, T, T, ...
...
-87, (T), F, (T), F, T, T, ...
98, (F), F, (T), F, F, T, ...
```

And `SUM()` can take any number of parameters: `SUM(1)` and `SUM(5, 7, ..., 3455)` are all possible.

Are there some smart algorithms for finding a list of attributes `L` where `SUM(L)` would yields to the maximum result?
Obviously, brute forcing is not feasible for this large data set.

It would be awesome if there is a way to find not only the maximum but top N lists.

**EDIT**
It seems like it is not possible to find THE answer without brute forcing. If I changed the question to find a "good estimation", would there be a good way to do it?
Or, what if I said the cardinality of L is fixed to something like 10, would there be a way to calculate the L?
I would be happy with any.

Comment: Are the record numbers (2,29,..-87,98) unique?

Comment: no, the numbers are not unique

Comment: First question: can you do something like SUM(A1, not A2, A3) and so earn the 'score' of "not A2" (i.e. where A2 is false)?  
Second question: is there any limit to the cardinality of L?

Comment: Yes, SUM(A1, not A2, A3) can be done

Comment: That's really bad news :)

Comment: There is no limit to the cardinality of L, it can be something between 1 and 5K

Comment: @gd1 I meant it can be done if it is required in finding the max SUM(A1, A3). I'm not interested in finding out something like SUM(A1, not A2)

Comment: Uh, OK. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Dammit, if there weren't negative numbers, this would just be "return empty list".

Comment: The answer is no. There's no good algorithm. Proof of NP-completeness to be posted shortly...

Comment: @Bing, what you meant by `max SUM(A1, A3)`? sum(A1, A3) is already number

Comment: @pkuderov sorry for the confusion, I said max SUM(A1, A3) because I meant SOME A1 and A3 which would yield to the maximum sum.

Comment: also maybe negative numbers can be transformed to positive by inversing attributes (-87 -> 87 with every Ax' = not Ax)

Comment: @Bing, is finding maximum is a strict condition in your case or you'll be ok with 'good' result? you can brute force for small queries and use different heuristics for the others. So maybe you should reformulate you question and try to find 'good' heuristic at least?

Comment: @pkuderov no, negative numbers cannot be transformed to positive by inversing.

Comment: I'm agreeing with user on this one. If you look at this as a graph problem, then you need to find cliques (based on attributes, so N=5000) just to determine what gets summed. In the worst case, you'll have to find the maximum clique which is NP-Complete. You can probably use a branch and bound algorithm to limit things somewhat, but given that you have a hidden coefficient of 2 million, it's probably not going to help much.

Comment: I've been doing some experiments and I'm wondering what the distribution of T/F flags is and also the range and distribution of the scores for the records. The reason I'm asking is that using a simple algorithm that incrementally adjusts existing solutions, this gave a the best result after very few steps (though on a smaller data set), so I'm wondering whether the distribution doesn't affect the behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, this problem is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). Your options are limited to finding a good but non-maximal solution with an approximation algorithm, or using branch-and-bound and hoping that you don't hit exponential runtime.

**Proof of NP-completeness**

To prove that your problem is NP-complete, we reduce the [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem to your problem. Suppose we have a set `U` of `N` elements, and a set `S` of `M` subsets of `U`, where the union of all sets in `S` is `U`. The set cover problem asks for the smallest subset `T` of `S` such that every element of `U` is contained in an element of `T`. If we had a polynomial-time algorithm to solve your problem, we could solve the set cover problem as follows:

First, construct a table with `M+N` rows and `M` attributes. The first `N` rows are "element" rows, each corresponding to an element of `U`. These have value "negative enough"; `-M-1` should be enough. For element row `i`, the `j`th attribute is true if the corresponding element is *not* in the `j`th set in `S`.

The last `M` rows are "set" rows, each corresponding to a set in `S`. These have value `1`. For set row `N+i`, the `i`th attribute is *false* and all others are true.

The values of the element rows are small enough that any choice of attributes that excludes all element rows beats any choice of attributes that includes any element row. Since the union of all sets in `S` is `U`, picking all attributes excludes all element rows, so the best choice of attributes is the one that includes the most set rows without including any element rows. By the construction of the table, a choice of attributes will exclude all element rows if the union of the corresponding sets is `U`, and if it does, its score will be better the fewer attributes it includes. Thus, the best choice of attributes corresponds directly to a minimum cover of `S`.

If we had a good algorithm to pick a choice of attributes that produces the maximal sum, we could apply it to this table to generate the minimum cover of an arbitrary `S`. Thus, your problem is as hard as the NP-complete set cover problem, and you should not waste your time trying to come up with an efficient algorithm to generate the perfect choice of attributes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the proof. Could one argue that this also looks like a variant of the subset sum problem ?(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Complexity)

Comment: @Ioannis: Maybe. I didn't come up with a way to reduce subset sum to this problem before I came up with the set cover reduction.

Comment: +1, Nice proof. I fixed some small typos with the indices, revert/fix them if I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a genetic algorithm approach, starting out with a certain (large) number of random attribute combinations, letting the worst x% die and mutating a certain percentage of the remaining population by adding/removing attributes.

There is no guarantee that you will find the optimal answer, but a good chance to find a good one within reasonable time.

Comment: There's a problem with that (in fact I updated the answer). The columns do not always yield the same score. It depends on the columns you already selected.

Comment: I see - I ignored/misinterpreted the little word "and"

Comment: Edited my answer, as it was based on a misunderstanding

Comment: @Bing as you are now actively looking for ways to find "good" answers instead of optimal ones: are there any additional properties of the numbers and or the boolean matrix that are known? Are the numbers equally distributed? Over what range? Is the matrix sparsely populated, or are true and false values equally distributed?

Answer (score 0):

No polynomial algorithms to solve this problem come to my mind. I can only suggest you a greedy heuristic:

1. For each attribute, compute its `expected_score`, i.e. the addend it would bring to your SUM, if selected *alone*. In your example, the score of 1 is 3 - 87 = -84.
2. Sort the attributes by `expected_score` in non-increasing order.
3. By following that order, greedily add to `L` the attributes. Call `actual_score` the score that the attribute `a` will actually bring to your sum (it can be better or worse than `expected_score`, depending on the attributes you already have in `L`). **If `actual_score(a)` is not strictly positive, discard `a`.**

This will not give you the optimal `L`, but I think a "fairly good" one.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: see below why this approach will not give the best results.*

My first approach would be to start off with the special case L={} (which should give the sum of all integers) and add that to a list of solutions. From there add possible attributes as restrictions. In the first iteration, try each attribute in turn and remember those that gave a better result. After that iteration, put the remembered ones into a list of solutions.

In the second iteration, try to add another attribute to each of the remembered ones. Remember all those that improved the result. Remove duplicates from the remembered attribute combinations and add these to the list of solutions. Note that {m,n} is the same as {n,m}, so skip redundant combinations in order not to blow up your sets.

Repeat the second iterations until there are no more possible attributes that could be added to improve the final sum. If you then order the list of solutions by their sum, you get the requested solution.

Note that there are ~20G ways to select three attributes out of 5k, so you can't build a data structure containing those but you must absolutely generate them on demand. Still, the sheer amount can produce lots of temporary solutions, so you have to store those efficiently and perhaps even on disk. You can exploit the fact that you only need the previous iteration's solutions for the next iterations, not the ones before.

Another restriction here is that you can end up with less than N best solutions, because all those below L={} are not considered. In that case, I would accept all possible solutions until you have N solutions, and only once you have the N solutions discard those that don't give an improvement over the worst one.

**Python code**:

```
solutions = [{}]
remembered = [{}]
while remembered:
    tmp = remembered
    remembered = []
    for s in remembered:
        for xs in extensions(s):
            if score(xs) > score(s)
                remembered.append(xs)
    solutions.extend(remembered)
```

**Why this doesn't work:**

Consider a temporary solution consisting of the three records

```
-2, T, F
-2, F, T
+3, F, F
```

The overall sum of these is -1. When I now select the first attribute, I discard the second and third record, giving a sum of -2. When selecting the second attribute, I discard the first and third, giving the same sum of -2. When selecting both the first and second attribute, I discard all three records, giving a sum of zero, which is an improvement.

Comment: Doesn't work. It could easily be the case that you need to add a bunch of attributes that worsen the sum before later additions make them worthwhile.

Comment: You're right. I added an according note and an example that proves your claim. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'll try a second approach, based on the potential of a temporary solution. Basically, the best improvement to a solution that you can possibly get is bounded by minus the sum of all records with a negative score, if you manage to throw out all negative records by a setof attributes. So, instead of requiring that a temporary solution actually improves things, you can discard the solution when it doesn't and when its potential is less than the actual value of the current solution. Need to think about that first...